# How to escape password in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, special-characters

In my pipeline script I want to execute the following `sh` command including a password (e.g. 123$ABC) with special characters:

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'id', keyFileVariable: 'keyFile', passphraseVariable: '', usernameVariable: 'user')]) {

  sh "ssh -i $keyFile ${user}@${virtualMachine} -C \"CONTAINER_NAME=${dockerContainerName} DOCKER_TAG=${dockerImageTag} JASYPT_MASTER_PASSWORD='${JASYPT_MASTER_PW}' docker-compose -f /tmp/docker-compose-jenkins.yml up\""

}
```

How must the command look like to obtain the special characters in my password?

Comment: You can escape the special character using ```\``` Example: 123\$ABC

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, the possible solution is to decode the password variable, something like:

```
def encodedPassword = URLEncoder.encode("$JASYPT_MASTER_PW",'UTF-8')
```

and then use the **encodedPassword** variable instead of **JASYPT_MASTER_PW**

Let's try